# Add combobox in extjs grid for only one row

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have an extjs grid which shows data from a store. The last column is always empty except for the entry in store where, a flag `is_deleted=0`(Only one entry will have is_deleted=0). I have to show a combobox for this entry with values edit and delete.

The current grid code I have is as follows:

```
Ext.define('TasoDesktop.view.taso.popups.accountComments.AccountCommentsGrid', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.GridPanel',
alias: 'widget.tasoAccountCommentsGrid',

title: 'Previous Comments',

initComponent: function () {
    this.store = 'AccountLevelComments';

    this.columns = [
        { header: 'Date Entered', dataIndex: 'modified_dt', flex: 0},
        { header: 'Comment', dataIndex: 'c_comment', flex: 0 },
        { header: 'Entered by', dataIndex: 'sid', flex: 0 },
        { header: 'Expiry Date', dataIndex: 'valid_until_dt', flex: 0 },
        { header: 'Action', flex: 0 }
    ];

    this.height = 400;
    this.width = 900;

    this.viewConfig = {
        stripeRows: true
    };

    this.autoScroll = true;

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

Only one of the Action column( with is_deleted = 0 in the store) should have the combo-box. How should I include the combobox for it based on the store value?

Answer (score 2):

Any column editor is defined per-column so you cannot define an editor for column-and-row. What you *can* do is to conditionally disable the editing for rows that do not match your criteria.

For that, listen to [beforeedit event](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.Editing-event-beforeedit) and return false from the listener is the criteria do not match.

Answer (score 0):

Add xtype : 'checkcolumn' for the column having header as Action and assign the dataindex property for that column with value ,you need to assign from the store.